# fell asleep vs had fallen asleep

Tags: difference, past-perfect, past-simple

Is it possible to say "When I got home, Ben was lying on the sofa. The TV was on, but he wasn't watching it. He *fell* asleep and was snoring loudly"?

The answer is "*had fallen asleep*".

Could anyone explain the differences in this context and why the answer is so?

Comment: _He fell asleep_ would mean that he went to sleep just as the speaker arrived home!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"fell asleep" means he just fell asleep, "had fell asleep" means he was already asleep. This context says that you got home and that he was *already* asleep, so it is "had fallen asleep".